# Android. Фрагменты накладываются друг на друга

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Конечно же, я почитал темы здесь и в гугле. И не нашёл решения. Думаю, оно есть, однако, мне не далось. Только начал пользоваться фрагментами. Делаю с ними второе приложение. В первом заработали после танцев с бубнами. Второй раз не получается, хотя делаю ровно то же самое. На мой взгляд.
По теме: при открытии приложения создаётся первый фрагмент (StartFragment), создаётся он в коде через replace. В нём две кнопки, при нажатии на каждую открывается какой-то новый фрагмент. И вот новый открывается, а старый остаётся на заднем фоне. Пробовал делать ремув,он утверждает, что ремувается, однако, остаётся на экране даже в этом случае.
Активити, где происходит отображение фрагментов:

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.artemonre.justjob.BaseActivity;
import com.artemonre.justjob.BaseController;
import com.artemonre.justjob.BaseFragment;
import com.artemonre.justjob.R;

public class StartActivity extends BaseActivity {

private BaseController baseController;
private StartFragment fragment;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragment = new StartFragment();
        fragmentTransaction
                .replace(R.id.frgmCont, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

public void replaceFragment(int containerId, BaseFragment fragment, boolean popBackStack){
    fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction
            .replace(containerId, fragment)
            .commit();
}
}
```

Код фрагмента:

```
    public class StartFragment extends BaseFragment{

    private Button regButton, autButton;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;
    View rootView;

    private BaseFragment fragment;
    private StartFragmentController controller;
    private ViewGroup container;
    private FragmentStartBinding binding;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, null);
        binding = FragmentStartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, true);
        this.container = container;

        findViewes();
        setOnClickListener();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

   private void replaceFragment(BaseFragment fragment){
        controller.replaceFragment(container, fragment);
    }

    class StartOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(v.getId()){
                case (R.id.reg_button):
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "regButton onClick");
                    fragment = new RegistrationFragment();
                    break;
                case(R.id.aut_button):
                    fragment = new AuthorizationFragment();
                    break;
            }
            if(fragment != null)
                replaceFragment(fragment);
        }
    }
}
```

Библиотека фрагментов сейчас использована не саппорт, это просто было ради эксперимента. С саппорт происходит абсолютно то же. Никаких эксепшенов обнаружено не было. Заранее благодарен.

UPD.
Код "контроллера"

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.artemonre.justjob.BaseFragment;
import com.artemonre.justjob.BaseFragmentController;

public class StartFragmentController extends BaseFragmentController {

    private StartActivity activity;

    public StartFragmentController(final Context context, BaseFragment fragment){
        super(fragment);
        activity = (StartActivity)context;
    }

    public void replaceFragment(ViewGroup container, BaseFragment fragment){
        activity.replaceFragment(container.getId(), fragment, true);
    }

}
```

UPD. BaseFragment. В нём сейчас особо ничего нет (только начал делать приложение и возникла проблема, после чего начал отсекать разные компоненты)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import static com.artemonre.justjob.BaseActivity.LOG_TAG;

public class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements MainContract.View {

    BaseFragmentController uiController;
    protected View rootView = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView.setClickable(true);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что у вас за контроллер? Разместите его код

Comment: Да, что делает вот этот метод интересно: `controller.replaceFragment(container, fragment);`

Comment: Прослойка. Учусь не делать прямых вызовов. В общем, метод просто перенаправляет из фрагмента в активити. Сейчас выложу код.

Comment: @АртёмБальзан немного не понял, вот у вас при нажатии на кнопку в первом фрагменте, появляется второй, а первый не удаляется. Тоесть проблема в наложении?

Comment: Ну да, второй накладывается поверх. То есть, он его находит, куда надо вставляет, только вот старый не убирает. После часов ковыряния подозреваю, что я теряю где-то активити и первый фрагмент добавляю в один экземпляр, а второй - в другой. Вот только, где оно теряется...

Comment: Да, тут вы правы. После поворота экрана, ваш контроллер "отрывается" от реальности :)

Comment: Если бы проблема была с поворотом экрана, это был бы совсем другой вопрос... Однако, ни до каких поворотов я даже не дошёл, даже на ровном месте не верно отрабатывает.

Comment: @АртёмБальзан как дела?

Comment: Пока без изменений. Где-то прям такой косяк, что ничего не помогает. Хотя я определил, что экземпляр активити один и тот же, фрагменты тоже. Где и с чем теряется связь, никак не пойму. Однако, проблема точно должна быть подобного рода. Ибо, когда я пробовал делать ремув (чисто для эксперимента), фрагмент удалялся (я сделал вывод потому, что после одного нажатия дальнейшие не отслеживались), однако, оставался на виду (толи появлялся новый, толи чёрт его знает, как это происходит)... (не представляю, понятно ли что-то из этого сообщения)

Comment: @АртёмБальзан по моему способу сделали?

Comment: Да, конечно. По всем сделал по очереди, не зря же вопрос задавал, чтоб услышать ответ. Думаю, что проблема глубже, чем в использовании одного метода, ищу.

Answer (score 2):

Я нашёл ответ на просторах Инета, который помог мне в этой ситуации.

В **main_activity.xml** нужно заменить `fragment .....>` на `FrameLayout .....>`. Мне помогло. У меня контекстное меню - действия не выполнялись, потому что фрагменты накладывались. Теперь всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

"По теме: при открытии приложения создаётся первый фрагмент (StartFragment), создаётся он в коде через replace."

Первый фрагмент должен создаваться с помощью метода .add

В вашем случае:

```
fragmentTransaction
            .replace(R.id.frgmCont, fragment)
            .commit();
```

нужно заменить на:

```
fragmentTransaction
            .add(R.id.frgmCont, fragment)
            .commit();
```

UPD. Сотрите ваш код полностью и сделайте по другому:

1. В активности, создаем фрагмент используя операторы .add , .commit , где указываем разметку нашего контейнера и 1 фрагмент
2. При нажатии на кнопку, заменяем 1 фрагмент на 2 используя метод replace , где указываем разметку нашего контейнера для фрагментов и сам 2 фрагмент.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можете подсказать, почему это принципиально? Переделаю - проверю.

Comment: @АртёмБальзан я не полностью ответил на ваш вопрос. Поэтому пытаюсь разобраться что вы хотите сделать)
метода replace - заменяет один фрагмент на другой, а вы получается заменяется пустой фрагмент(которого нет) на ваш) Не логично)

Comment: Не принципиально, если контейнер пустой, `replace` и `add` делают по сути одно и то же.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja делает одно и тоже, но логику использования методов нарушают)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

У меня была такая же проблема недавно, и мне помогло.

Comment: Благодарю за совет. Как я и говорил - в данный момент в коде не саппорт только потому, что это очередная попытка. Пробовал и так, и так.

Comment: А добавьте код BaseFragment еще

Comment: Да, сейчас сделаю. (Чувствую, сейчас основная проблема будет в распутывании того, что я понаписал...)

Comment: Если фрагмент из саппорта, то и менеджер должен быть оттуда. И вообще на последнем IO говорили, что про фрагменты и проч. из пакета `android.app.*` лучше забыть и пользоваться только саппортом.

Answer (score 0):

У вас тут путаница с фрагментами, первый вы вставляете в разметку активити:

```
replace(R.id.frgmCont, fragment)
```

А второй по сути в разметку первого:

```
activity.replaceFragment(container.getId(), fragment, true);
```

где `container` будет вью первого фрагмента

```
controller.replaceFragment(container, fragment);
```

Вот поэтому ничего и не работает как ожидается.

Comment: Хм, то есть, я неверно решил, что контэйнер в этом случае именно то вьюгруп, куда добавляется фрагмент в активити? Сейчас опробую. Спасибо, что продрались через мой код и оказали помощь.

Comment: Это будет корень `R.layout.fragment_start`

Comment: Ваша активити знает куда фрагменты вставлять, первый параметр метода вашего контроллера не нужен. Этим избежите путаницы.

Comment: Странно, мои опыты показывают, что это один и тот же элемент - айди совпадают. В целом, согласен, что это лишний элемент и я его убрал. Вот только ситуация не изменилась, к сожалению.

Comment: Айди вы сам задаете, можно хоть десять вью сделать с одним айди :)

Answer (score 0):

У меня бьыла подобная проблема , оказалось что `layout` второго фрагмента попросту не имеет бэкграунда и поэтому они накладывались друг на друга.

Приведу пример код:

`loadFragment(new Fragment_1());`

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.animation2, R.anim.animation, R.anim.close, R.anim.closein);
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

в корневой разметке я просто сделал бэкграунд.
Понимаю , что возможно это костыль но мне помогло.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="?attr/layoutBackground" //вот тут или же просто добавьте аттрибут android:background">@drawable/background
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

или типа того)

Comment: Да, это костыль. И сейчас я пока пользуюсь именно им. И всё равно благодарю за отзывчивость. :)

Comment: Отпишите как найдете решение

Comment: Конечно, обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл проблему. Сидит за компьютером, как обычно. По существу - проблема в Датабиндинге (с которым я не умею обращаться). Хорошего решения не нашёл - некогда разбираться, что именно не так сделал при биндинге, поэтому просто его удалил из проекта (благо, было немного) и теперь все фрагменты работают, меняются, появляются нормально.

Answer (score 0):

У меня эта проблема решилась использованием контейнера **<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>** вместо **<fragment.>** для SupportFragmentManager.
А то, каким образом вставлять первый фрагмент, через **add** или **replace**, в данной ситуации значения не имеет. Работает и тот и другой способ.